# Getting a value from second Form using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to get value from  second (form2 to form1) automatically or by press button on second form but i cant

im able to get value from form1 to form2 but no form2 to form1

i try this one

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    Form1 ytr = new Form1();

    ytr.totalcost.Text = textBox3.Text;
}
```

not working

UPDATE ( code on form 2 )

```
namespace Carprogram
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            multpl();
        }



        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            multpl();
        }

        private void multpl()
        {
            int a, b;

            bool isAValid = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
            bool isBValid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out b);

            if (isAValid && isBValid)
                textBox3.Text = (a * b).ToString();

            else
                textBox3.Text = "Invalid input";


        }

        private Form1 form1Instance { get; set; }

        public Form2 (Form1 form1)
        {
            this.form1Instance = form1;
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            this.form1Instance.totalcost.Text = textBox3.Text;


        }


    }
}
```

Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You never *show* the `ytr` instance of `Form1`.  Do you already have an instance shown?  How are your forms related?

Comment: You can create a public class for transfer what you want.

Comment: Create a private variable inside `ytr` called `_TotalCost` then create a public getter called `TotalCost`. Inside that getter return `_TotalCost`.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a *new* instance of `Form1` and never showing it.  Instead, you want to set the value on the instance of `Form1` that you *already have*.

Presumably `Form1` creates and shows an instance of `Form2`, yes?  Since `Form2` is expecting to interact back with `Form1`, it should require a reference to it.  Add that requirement in your `Form2` constructor.  Something like this:

```
private Form1 form1Instance { get; set; }

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1Instance = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

That way it's required when creating an instance of `Form2`.  So in `Form1` when you create that instance, you can pass a reference to itself:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

Then later in your click handler you can reference the instance that you're holding in that property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.form1Instance.totalcost.Text = textBox3.Text;
}
```

From here you can even continue to refactor the functionality into custom simple classes instead of passing around form references.  There are a variety of approaches you could take, including custom events or messages of some kind.  But ultimately you'll need to refer to the *existing* instance of `Form1` in order to change anything on that instance, not create a *new* one.

Comment: or use `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First().totalcost.Text = "...";` which presumes that there is exactly one open form of type `Form1`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I might argue that this would be hiding a dependency instead of explicitly advertising it, but that would just be covering the fact that I didn't know about `Application.OpenForms`.  That'd work too, with that caveat of course.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @NAWAFWABS: That's called a `NullReferenceException`.  What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @NAWAFWABS: Then it would appear that you've made a mistake somewhere.  Update the question to include the new code you've written and indicate specifically where the exception is being thrown and which object is `null`.

Comment: @David i do it now

Comment: @NAWAFWABS: Your code now has *two* constructors in `Form2`.  One of them sets the new property, the other one does not.  Which one did you use?  Remove the parameterless constructor entirely, since `Form2` *requires* a reference to `Form1`.  (Basically, you entirely missed the second code snippet in this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is using delegate:

in Form2:

```
public Action<int> OnSetTotalCost;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1 ytr = new Form1();
  var talCost = int.parse(textBox3.Text);
  if(OnSetTotalCost != null) OnSetTotalCost(talCost);
}
```

and in Form1 class

```
var form2 = new Form2(this); // u dont need to pass form1
form2.OnSetTotalCost = SetTotalCost;
form2.Show();
```

and u can define `SetTotalCost` as:

```
private void SetTotalCost(int totalCost)
{
  txtTotalcost.Text = totalCost.ToSttring();
}
```